# get value from object data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, dataset

this is a part of my Stored Procedure :

```
Create procedure sp_Units_GetUnitState  
@PadidehOrAtkinsCode int  
as
    Select State from Units where ID = @PadidehOrAtkinsCode  
go
```

I have a DataSet (.XSD) file which has my StoredProcedure (named GetDataBy1 here)
[image]
I pass the parameter like this :

```
odsUnit.SelectParameters["PadidehOrAtkinsCode"].DefaultValue =  
txtPadidehOrAtkinsCode.Text;
```

Now I want to fill my textbox Text property with the `State` field I had in my stored procedure, what should I do to get the value from osdUnit?
[image]

Comment: check my answer it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object of your stored procedure and call the GetData function. No need to assign select parameters to your objectdatasource. Follow below example: I assumed your dataset name is dataset1.

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();  // for temporary storage
DataSet1TableAdapters.sp_Units_GetUnitState  objAda = new DataSet1TableAdapters.sp_Units_GetUnitState();
dt1 = objAda.GetData(txtPadidehOrAtkinsCode.Text);

// Now get the state from the datatable
string state = dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```